# React pre-processing props

Tags: reactjs

I'd to know if there's any component or helper function to pre-process/transform properties before delivering to the component itself.

I've using the redux's `connect` function to achieve this behaviour but for components that doesn`t connect to the redux store doesn't make much sense. The following illustrates the ideal solution:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => { ... }
const propsProcessor = (props) => {
    //do something here and return the processed props 
}

export default processingProps(propsProcessor)(MyComponent);
```

This way I could pass an array to the component, group into an json and  use it inside the component.

Comment: You probably want the HOC (Higher Order Component) pattern. You can find the pattern here https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: so.. a HoC? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Yes, a HoC. But I wonder if there's an existing one with this purpose.